# Is there any way to check user's permission on SSRS 2012?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

There are several folders on SSRS Reporting server, we add users into those folders using AD directory. We never had this problem but now one user,  he was not in reporting server before but now user can see all the folders and all the reports on the server.

I have checked his permission by going on Folder Setting and site setting -> security(cannot find user), I think somehow he was added in BUILTIN\Administrators group. Is there anyway to check what level of permission he has? How to see what users are added in BUILTIN\Administrators?

I am running the following query but it is not helping.

```
select C.UserName, D.RoleName, D.Description, E.Path, E.Name 
from dbo.PolicyUserRole A
   inner join dbo.Policies B on A.PolicyID = B.PolicyID
   inner join dbo.Users C on A.UserID = C.UserID
   inner join dbo.Roles D on A.RoleID = D.RoleID
   inner join dbo.Catalog E on A.PolicyID = E.PolicyID
order by C.UserName
```

Answer (score 0):

For particular account try using `EXEC xp_logininfo 'account_name'` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190369.aspx).
As for the second question, you could try executing `EXEC xp_logininfo 'BUILTIN\Administrators', 'members'` which should result in  list of logins with account names and type (http://www.wisdom-soup.com/blog/performance-audit/to-find-sql-server-login-group-members-builtinadministrators/).